# How to write query to select value without repeat same values again?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select `employee_id` from this table, if there is 00001 is four times, I need to get it only once.

How to write query for this scenario?

```
id  company_ID  Employee_ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
    1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-66   49  Female            
    2   EMPL        00001       Komala      Mother      30-Oct-39   76  Female            
    3   EMPL        00001       Varshini    Daughter    29-Apr-04   11  Female            
    4   EMPL        00001       Vasudevan   Employee    15-Jul-62   53  Male    
    5   EMPL        00002       Siddharth   Son         1-Jun-00    15  Male              
    6   EMPL        00002       Poongavanam Mother      21-Oct-39   76  Female            
    7   EMPL        00002       Aruna       Spouse      16-Sep-68   47  Female            
    8   EMPL        00002       Abirami     Daughter    7-May-97    18  Female            
    9   EMPL        00002       Murali      Employee    7-Oct-67    48  Male
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_ID FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `distinct`:

```
select distinct Employee_ID from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT Employee_ID from tablename
```